# I am trying to connect my Website with Remix Ethereum IDE and getting one issue { setInstructor} function is not responding.help me with set function

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, web3-providers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

   

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h1>Faculty Instructor</h1>

        <h2 id="instructor"></h2>

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text">

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Instructor Age</label>
        <input id="age" type="text">

        <button id="button">Update Instructor</button>


    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.unpkg.com/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
       if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));
        }

        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        
        
        


contract = new web3.eth.Contract( abi , '0x4721D040Ef28BA9b18B3d0D7d41443126c1A68D4');
console.log(contract);

contract.methods.getInstructor().call().then(function(result ,error)
       
       {
            if(!error)
                {
                    $("#instructor").html(result[0]+' ('+result[1]+' years old)');
                    console.log(result);
                }
            else
                console.error(error);
        });

        $("#button").click(function() {
            Faculty.setInstructor($("#name").val(), $("#age").val());
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `contract.methods.setInstructor(...)` to execute the function required.

Comment: yes sir I used it but set function is not responding in website help me with the code sir./*
        $("#button").click(function() {
            FacultyContract.methods.setInstructor($("#fname").val(), $("#age").val());
        });                                                                                                                             */

Comment: Why do you use `Faculty` or `FacultyContract`? They are never defined in the code. The only instantiation of a contract is `contract = new web3.eth.Contract(..)`, so you have to use `contract.methods.setInstructor(..)`.